# parsing function with multiple arguments to mapM_ in haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm starting to learn Haskell and was wondering, how does one print elements in a list, out into a single concatenated string with a defined space character. I've achieved this in the script below.

However I'm hoping to write the putStrSep function such that i can specify the separator as an argument. Instead of having it hardcoded in the example below.

```
#/usr/bin/env runghc 
import System.Environment   --for the getArgs function

-- Concatenate my own string
putStrSep :: String -> IO()
putStrSep x = putStr (x ++ " ")


--Prints the list of arguments
main = do 
 putStrLn "Usage: helloworld.hs your full name"
 args <- getArgs    --returns you a list of string
 putStr "Your name is: "
 mapM_ putStrSp args
 putStrLn "\nGood bye!"
```

Comment: It's better to avoid IO when you can, replacing `putStrSep' :: String -> [String] -> IO()` with `strSep :: String -> [String] -> String` because it gives you more flexibility with what to do with the output other than popping it directly on the screen right now. (You'll thank me when you switch a program from command line interface to GUI - separate the UI from the processing.) But then you may as well use `intercalate :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [a]` from `Data.List` because `type String = [Char]` anyway, as in [the answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23355494/1598537), directly in `main`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could implement your `putStrSep` like this

```
putStrSep :: Char -> String -> IO ()
putStrSep sep str = putStr (str ++ [sep])
```

Note: your `mapM_ ...` need to be replaced by something like `mapM_ (putStrSep '\t') args`

Or you could use `intercalate` (from `Data.List`), and replace that `mapM_ ...` with

```
putStrLn $ intercalate " " args
```

or

```
putStrLn $ intercalate [sep] args
```

`sep` is your separator character.

Comment: `intersperse` doesn't concatenate the strings. You want `intercalate` instead.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Overlooked. Thank you. Answer updated.

Comment: thanks for the intercalate suggestion, it works

I've also tried using the suggested putStrSep function with mapM_
`mapM_ putStrSep "\t" args` but doesn't work

Comment: @altimit The first parameter of `putStrSep` is a `Char`, not a `String`, as its type indicates. However, if you want its first parameter be a `String`, you need to change its type to `String -> String -> IO ()`, and its definition to `putStrSep sep str = putStr (str ++ sep)`.

Comment: Sorry even when I changed `"\t"` to `'\t'` it still doesnt work. Maybe my understanding of mapM_ is not adequate here

Comment: @altimit Use it like this: `mapM_ (putStrSep '\t') args`

Comment: @altimit Or better still, `putStrLn $ intercalate ['\t'] args` as in the answer.